# List<string> in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, list

I'm cool with C# but am new to C++. I searched but found lots of different solutions which mostly do not work maybe because there are different versions of C++.

I'm using turbo C++ 4.5, I want something like C#'s List of strings

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("1");
```

I know a bit about C++ arrays, but I do not know the count of items at declaration time and that's why I want List-like solution so that I can declare once and add items later.

someone told me I should do it using pointers but I don't know how. Is it possible? or there any ways?

**Please if you have an answer explain it cause I really like to learn, thanks.**

Comment: The guy who told you to use pointers apparently has no idea how C++ works, so ignore their "advice".

Comment: turbo c++ 4.5? really?

Comment: yes unfortunately turbo C++ 4.5 and I have to.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari: This compiler (*Why* do you need to use a compiler almost as old as you are?) predates the standard containers, so you're pretty much stuck with using Borland's BIDS containers. If memory serves, what you're probably looking for is TArrayAsVector. You should have online help that gives examples of how to use it. That said, I find it difficult to believe you can't use a newer compiler. Even if you're developing for MS-DOS or 16-bit Windows, you can use BC++ 5.02.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The equivalent to C# `List<T>` is [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). The C++ code that corresponds to your C# code is this:

```
using namespace std;
....
vector<string> s;
s.push_back("1");
```

You should not take the advice to write such a class for yourself. Where they are appropriate, always use the standard containers.

Comment: Thanks david. Now I just want to know how they use pointers in string array, I won't use it, just want to understand

Comment: Why do you say the equivelent is `std:vector`? `std::list` does support push back. I am not an expert in c# list but I would be amazed if it's `List`  does not support insert at any point, while `std::vector` does not(efficiently).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev C# List supports inserting at a specefic point.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari exactly. Then std::vector will not be able to handle that efficiently. I do not understand why the proposed container is a `std::vector`, not a `std::list`.

Comment: @Ivaylo std::vector has random access O(1). But std::list is a linked list. C# List<T> is badly named. It's a vector/array container rather than a linked list.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is correct, std::list<> and LinkedList<> are more equiv. (actually, std::forward_list<> probably).

Comment: Also @IvayloStrandjev, in C++ the prefered container should always be std::vector. In most cases the performance is way better (one reason is cache misses in std::list).

Comment: @Skalli There are times when O(1) insertion is desirable, and then the list wins. When you need to iterate across the container, or have random access, then vector wins.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's not entirely true. In most cases the vector wins here too. Bjarne Stroustrup showed it in a keynote presentation not long ago. I was surprised myself, but that's why he pointed out to use std::vector. Of course there are some use cases left for std::list, but it should only be used when it's really neccessary.

Comment: For containers with few enough elements I'm sure that is so. But for huge containers I'd expect a list to be strong. But I'm not expert and obviously bow to Bjarne's knowledge.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The sad part is, he prepared a graph for his presentation, but it wasn't displayed (he said it was embarrassing...). But he said that it hold true because there are many cache misses in std::list. A lot less in std::vector because the memory is aligned and continuous.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan here is a [link](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12Cpp11Style.pdf) to the slides of the keynote I was writing about (The graph is on slide 45). [Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style?format=html5) is the keynote itself.